# What is the deference between "firebase-messaging" and "firebase-inappmessaging-display"?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle, firebase-in-app-messaging

When i use Android Studio to add firebase in app messaging it adds this dependency to build gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.1.2'
```

but it deosn't work till i add this one:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.6'
```

what are the differences here? #firebase-inappmessaging-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**firebae-inappmessaging-display**

Firebase In-App Messaging helps you engage your app's active users by sending them targeted, contextual messages that encourage them to use key app features. For example, you could send an in-app message to get users to subscribe, watch a video, complete a level, or buy an item. You can customize messages as cards, banners, modals, or images, and set up triggers so that they appear exactly when they'd benefit your users most.

**firebase-messaging**

Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably send messages at no cost.

Comment: so firebase-messaging is for notification  and In-App Messaging is for contextual messages thank you sir